# How to focus or show menu bar item in Qt

Tags: qt, menu, menuitem, menubar, qmainwindow

I'm working in my thesis project, I need to know if it's possible to "open" automatically a menu item in my QMainWindow. I mean, if my menu bar is:

```
    File        Help
       -Open      -About...
       -Close     -Manual
       ...        ...
```

How can I open the menu item and show the submenus without clicking them? Is there something like:

```
ui->menubar->items[0].show();
```

To open the "File" menu.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help.

**EDIT: I found how to do in this [thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/7018-how-to-popup-and-close-a-QMenu)**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

QMenu popup() should do the trick.

For more info:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#popup